# How Can I See The Style Applied to a Widget?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, widget, css-cascade

Is there a way to see what style is being applied to a widget? In website development there is the **Style** tab in the Chrome Dev Tools which shows what style is applied and how this cascades and this is really useful to debug the page.

Is there a similar feature in Flutter?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/inspector are you looking for this?

Comment: I already use this for layout but it does not show things like fonts, colours and sizes.

Comment: Yes, it does. For example, if you have a text widget and want to view its font size, you can view your text widget in the widget details tree. If you hover with the mouse over the values at dependencies, then you see there e.g. DefaultTextStyle, which you can expand and in it you will find a TextStyle, where all the information is in it.

Comment: Thanks for that. Solves my issues completely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A small example to see information about fontSize, color etc. for a Text widget:

Open the Widget Inspector and switch to the Widet Details Tree
[image: Open the Widget Inspector and switch to the Widet Details Tree]

Hover over dependencies to see the DefaultTextStyle. For this to work, you must have enabled "hover inspection" in the Inspector Settings (top right gear icon).
[image]

[image: Hover over dependencies to see the DefaultTextStyle]

Open the DefaultTextStyle to see the style element, which has all the information.
[image: Open the DefaultTextStyle to see the style element, which has all the information]